# How can I export fields which are not being displayed in admin grid?

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, export, grid-layout

I have a custom admin grid, which shows the feedback given by customers during checkout.
I have 19 fields in the custom_table including entity_id, created_at and updated_at.

This is my form view:
[image]

This is my grid view:
[image]

everything works fine. Now when I export the grid as csv/ xml/ excel, it would only export the fields in the grid, but I want all the data in my database-table to be exported. How can I do that?
Also If i apply filter in that grid, only those rows should be exported.

> **note:** customer name and email_id are displayed by joining the sales/order table

This is my _prepareCollection() function in Grid.php

```
protected function _prepareCollection(){
    $collection = Mage::getModel('feedbacktest/feedback')->getCollection();
    // join the order table to display in the grid.
    $collection->join('sales/order', 'increment_id=order_id', array('orderId'=>'entity_id', 'custName'=>'concat(customer_firstname," ",customer_lastname)', 'custEmail'=>'customer_email'), null,'left');
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

Collection gives me all the data (as I require), but exported data contains only the data in the grid.

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can add in your grid columns that are visible only on export.
In the `_prepareColumns()` method add this:

```
if ($this->_isExport) { 
    $this->addColumn('col_id', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('helper_alias')->__('Header'),
        'index'  => 'col_id',
    ));
}
```

Just like any other column, just wrapped in `if ($this->_isExport) {`.

Comment: This works cool, but is there anyother way, by which I could skip adding columns, I mean like adding the column names to collection or so, because I have four more columns to be added and may be more in future.

Comment: maybe you can override the export methods in your grid. tage a look at `getCsvFile`, `getCsv`, `getXml`, `getExcelFile`, `getExcel` in `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid` and see what you can change

Comment: sure, i'll try and will post, if i am successful. Thanks!

Comment: @Marius : Actually I am using this method   https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/171754/51361  , for adding custom field on sales order grid. but when i export, the custom added column values not exported, how can i solve this error, could you pls help me.