# How can i get Tracking Number on Sales order grid

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, order-grid, shipment-tracking

I need tracking number on sales order grid,

[image]

Comment: Did you try this? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113814/how-to-add-tracking-number-column-to-order-grid?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with below.
Add below code in your **app/code/local/Vendor/Module/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Vendor_Module>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Vendor_Module>
  </modules>
  <global>
        <blocks>
          <module>
            <class>Vendor_Module_Block</class>
          </module>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <sales_order_grid>Vendor_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

Now create a file **app\code\local\Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Sales\Order\Grid.php** with below code.

```
<?php
class Vendor_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
{
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array("track_table"=>Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/shipment_track')), "main_table.entity_id = track_table.order_id",array('track_number'))->group('main_table.entity_id');
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        if ($this->_isExport) { 
            $this->addColumnAfter('track_number', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Track Order'),
                'index'  => 'track_table.track_number',
                'type' => 'text',
            ), 'status');
        }
        $this->addColumnAfter(
                'track_number',
                array(
                    'header'   => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Track Order'),
                    'align'    => 'left',
                    'type'     => 'text',
                    'index'    => 'track_number',
                    'filter_index'    => 'track_table.track_number',
                ),
                'status'
            );
        parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

Create file **app/etc/modules/Vendor_Module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Vendor_Module>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Vendor_Module>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Make sure config.xml is default file, and where i can create Observer.php file

Comment: Check updated answer for full file paths

Comment: reference id not dipsplay

Comment: Reference id? You mean carrier name?

Comment: see my question sceen shot

Comment: You have added an arrow on tacking number. And with above code, you will get the same number in orders grid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57730/discussion-between-rathinam-and-jaimin-sutariya).

Comment: @ jaimin : is any option available ?

Comment: @Rathinam, updated code to support export functionality. Please remove old files and create only these three files only.

Comment: @http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57730/discussion-between-rathinam-and-jaimin-sutariya

Comment: i will get error when i applied filter

Comment: for which filter you are getting this error?

Comment: purchased on filter by date

Comment: how to change order

Comment: order arrangement not working. order_id, purchased_on ....

Comment: could you pls join chat

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58990/room-for-rathinam-and-jaimin-sutariya

Comment: Hie @Jaimin Sutariya can you please help me out me same for magento 2